# how can i extract every pureProxy address from polkadot chain state?

Tags: polkadot

I need to take a snapshot of polkadot distribution, and make sure i handle all the inaccessible accounts. A subset of inaccessible accounts are **pure proxies**.

How can i create a list of pureProxies?

The only way i can see is to iterate through every single block of polkadot and query for `proxy.pureCreated`, but this will take far too long!

is there a solution i am missing?